# Where can i find the JAX-WS version shipped with Java 6?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, jax-rpc

I'm using Java 6 for learning more about web Services (JAX-WS). I also read that JAX-WS latest version is available with [Metro](http://metro.java.net/guide/), i.e. If you're not using JDK6 and planning to use JAX-WS, you can use Metro.

I would like to know which version of the JAX-WS is shipped with my JDK? I'm using  jdk1.6.0_22.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JAX-WS is part of standart JDK since version 6. You can learn which version of jax-ws by means wsgen or wsimport. You can find them bin subdirectory of your jdk installation.

> Q. How do I find out which version of
>   the JAX-WS RI I'm using? Run the
>   following command
>
> $ wsgen or wsimport -version
>   Alternatively, each JAX-WS jar has
>   version information in its
>   META-INF/MANIFEST.MF, such as this:
>   Build-Id: 12/14/2005 12:49
>   PM(dkohlert)  Build-Version: JAX-WS RI
>   2.0-12/14/2005 12:49 PM(dkohlert)-ea3

Comment: downvoter could explain his reasoning.. I would learn what was wrong with my answer.

Comment: It is even specified in the Goals of the specification: "Inclusion in J2SE JAX-WS 2.0 will prepare JAX-WS for inclusion in a future version of J2SE..."

Comment: JAX-WS is part of a standard Java runtime since version 6. I'm developing Web services and service clients with JAX-WS without anything but the standard Java libraries all the time. The answer is plain wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Well, according to [this link](http://jax-ws.java.net/faq/index.html#different_versions), Java 1.6 comes with at least JAX-RS 2.0. However, according to [this other link](http://metro.java.net/guide/Using_JAX_WS_2_x___Metro_1_x_2_0_with_Java_SE_6.html), Java 1.6 up to release 3 comes bundled with JAX-RS 2.0 and updates 4 and up contain the 2.1 api version.

If you want to use the latest available version you can get a zip file following [this link](http://jax-ws.java.net/2.2.3/), or if you are using Maven you must include the following dependency in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: According to the JAX-RS page: "[JAX-RS] provides the core of Metro project, inside GlassFish community"... Metro is just a "one-stop shop" for all your WebService needs, from SOAP to Corba to WCF to (some awkward version of) RESTful services. So if you use Metro you can potentially get other version of the JAX-WS api.